# Absence of velocity in energy conservation

Tags: rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia, solid-mechanics

[image]

Here we see a rod at rest hinged about a point. We want to know the angular speed of the rod when it becomes vertical as shown in the figure.

The solution which is given in the books goes like this.

Taking the black line as reference level,they say that initially,the rod had only potential energy which is $Mg\frac{L}{2}$. And they say that the final energy which will be present is $\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2$. And then they establish the equation $Mg\frac{L}{2}=\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2$. But I don't understand one thing. Since the center of mass of the rod here is moving,it surely has a linear velocity $v$. As we see in transrotational motion,where we use $\frac{1}{2}mv_{\mathrm{CM}}^2+\frac{1}{2}I_{\mathrm{CM}}\omega^2$. Why hasn't it been used in this case? Shouldn't the equation be $Mg\frac{L}{2}=\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2+\frac{1}{2}Mv^2$ where $v$ is the linear velocity of center of mass?

Answer (score 4):

When you're using the moment of inertia, you have to specify a reference point or axis. Then $\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2$ is the kinetic energy of the system in a rotation around that point.

So you have two equivalent ways to procede:

- Use $I_G$, the moment of inertia with the center of mass as a reference point. Since this point moves, then yes, it happens as you describe, you have to add $\frac{1}{2}mv(G)^2$ to the kinetic energy.
- Use $I$, the moment of inertia with the extremity of the bar as a reference point. Since this point doesn't move, you don't add anything to the kinetic energy.

The relation between $I$ and $I_G$ is exactly given by expressing the same kinetic energy with both methods. It's the parallel axis theorem.